# How to identify element under span in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm not able to identify the identifier under the span. I tried capturing using cypress studio also. Nothing captured

Full x-path is like this
/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/h4/span

unique identifier

class="logic_component_text">LunchMenu

I'm new to cypress. Any inputs highly appreciated.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of your HTML DOm along with the identifier you are trying?

Comment: Pls, add the test goal too. Do you need to interact with the element? Do you need to validate something there?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the element below if you hide the element using [invoke](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke#Function) and at the end of the case you will have such a DOM state in the cypress UI that you will be able to select and extract the element indentifier

`cy.get('.logic_component_text').invoke('hide').should('not.be.visible')`